# Why won't a value go out of scope when calling a function?

Tags: rust

Why will this not work?

```
struct Owned {
    bla: String,
}

struct Borrowed<'a> {
    bla: &'a str,
}

fn create_something() -> Borrowed { // error: nothing to borrow from
    let o = Owned {
        bla: String::from("bla"),
    };

    let b = Borrowed { bla: &o.bla };
    b
}
```

Whereas this will?

```
fn main() {
    let o = Owned {
        bla: String::from("bla"),
    };

    let b = create_something(&o.bla);

    //other_bla has been popped off stack
}

fn create_something(other_bla: &str) -> Borrowed {
    let b = Borrowed { bla: other_bla };
    b
}
```

The `other_bla` will be put onto the stack and then popped, which implies that it, the same as in to the 1st example, will go out of scope. The same thing, that is.

Why will only the 2nd example work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one works because inside your `main` function `o` goes out of scope *after* `b`, meaning the lifetime encapsulated in `b` is fulfilled.

Like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let o = Owned {                       // o exists
        bla: String::from("bla"),         // |
    };                                    // |
                                          // |
    let b = create_something(&o.bla);     // | b exists
                                          // | |
                                          // | b dropped
                                          // o dropped
}
```

The first one fails because `o` goes out of scope when the function exits, leaving `b` with an invalid reference.

```rust
fn create_something() -> Borrowed { // error: nothing to borrow from
    let o = Owned {                    // o exists
        bla: String::from("bla"),      // |
    };                                 // |
                                       // |
    let b = Borrowed { bla: &o.bla };  // | b exists
    b                                  // o dropped
                                       // : b has invalid ref
}
```

Comment: `o goes out of scope after b` --> why does it go after b? what ensures that it will do *after* `b`? not before, not at the same time

Comment: @mandiromi The declaration order will. Since `o` is declared *before* `b`, it outlives `b`.

Comment: Even if `o` is dropped before `b` it will work due to non-lexical lifetimes.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues is it `LIFO` then? Is it mentioned in the Rust docs?

Comment: Think of it as unwinding the objects created from last to first. It's not really a queue, which is what LIFO implies, just a reverse sequence.

Comment: But **why** is it that in the 2nd case (1st in your answer) the `o` will get dropped after `b`, whereas in the other case it'll be vise versa?

Comment: That's because you're trying to return `b`, so it necessarily outlives `o` as it needs to *exist*, un-dropped, in order to be a return value. You're forcing it to live longer than it usually would, as without that it'd get cleaned up in the usual order.